# Modify config file settings from bash

Tags: bash, configuration, sed, awk

I need to modify a config file from a bash script, changing the values of particular settings.  I need to make the change using common Linux tools (sed/awk/tr/etc.).  The config file can have identically named keys in different stanzas like this:

```
[section1]
key1=a
key2=b
[section2]
key1=a
key2=b
```

and the lines in each stanza can be in different order, with blank lines/comments between, etc.  I've tried sed but can't match across lines (so I can't match the stanza names).  Can someone suggest how to:
1. change the value associated with section1 key1 ?
2. Print to stdout the value associated with section1 key1 ?

Comment: This would have been a great on Stack Overflow. They seem to enjoy sed/awk questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with ex and a here script.  For your simple example:

```
ex $conf <<-EOF
   /^\[section1\]
   /^key1=
   s/=a/=c/
   wq
EOF
```

You search for the stanza header first, then for the variable name, then change the setting on that line only.

Comment: interesting...3 questions.  1:what if the key does not exist.  Will it modify the key in the next section if present there?  2.  Is ex found on most systems. 3: Can ex be used to print the value (of the key) to stdout?

Comment: can I replace the word "key1" with a parameter like $1 in bash?  I tried replacing it in your script above, but it doesn't work

Comment: 1. Yes 2. ex is the command line mode of vi so will be found on any system which has vi. 3. not that I know of.

Comment: Yes you can replace key1 with a variable. /^${1}= will work just the same as /^key1 if key1 is the value of the first positional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for Augeas, which will break the file down into its sections and settings in an editable hierarchy.  It's not exactly a standard tool in that it probably won't be installed on a given system by default, but will be available as a package for most Linuxes.

Comment: My script has to run on a variety of systems - I can only assume standard tools are installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to match across multiple lines; there's an excellent post on it here: [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)

Comment: I saw that before, but could not figure out how to match with an undefined number of lines between the first line (stanza), across n random lines, to match line (key).  Can you post an example?